# Datagrid with dynamic columns

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I have the bellow collection of objects with master detail data. I want to bind that collection to a datagrid. When user adds new OrderItem it will be reflected in new column which will be dynamically created. So for example one order can have 1 or 10ths order items (columns). I am flattening that Order - OrderItem in new object / CollectionView and binding it to datagrid. However, after the flattening I am not sure how get the Checkboxes states from Datagrid which will be used later for saving.

```
public class Order
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Customer{ get; set; }
    public ICollection<OrderItem> Items { get; set; }
}

public class OrderItem
{
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public bool Received { get; set; }      
}

| Order.Code | Order.Customer| OrderItem.Name| OrderItem.Name| OrderItem.Name|
| 123        | ABC           | TRUE          | TRUE          |  TRUE         |
| 456        | CDF           | TRUE          | TRUE          |  FALSE        |
| 789        | EFG           | TRUE          | FALSE         |  FALSE        |
```

Comment: That layout makes no sense, and your example doesn't help. Why would you have a true/false (or checkbox) under the order item name?

Comment: In OrderItem.Name columns I have a checkboxes in datagrid for indicating if the current item is received or not. Hence User can alternate the status of the Item via checking - unchecheking the checkboxex (for visualization purposes I am showing here the True/False values)